# Zend Framework - Limit db query not impacting paginator

Tags: php, sql-server, database, zend-framework

I have a following optimization issue. I have a large table so I want to limit query to fetch only first 20 rows. When the user is on the first page, fetch only 20 rows, when on second, fetch 40 etc...

I have following statement to obtain total number of rows:

```
$rowsCount = $this->_model->fetchRow( $this->_model->select()->from($this->_model, array('COUNT(*) as count')) )->count;
```

that is ofc working, and following statement to limit the query

```
$current_page = $this->_getParam('page');
$query->select(blahblahblah)->limit($current_page * 20);
```

also perfectly working. But now I have 2 options:
Make paginator fetch all rows - that way paginator is ok, but it's slow due to large table or 
Make paginator fetch the limited query, but that way paginator thinks there's only that number of rows I want to show.

Is it any way I can tell paginator to paginate 10000 entries but limit the query to fetch only first 20 * current page ?

Comment: Are you using Zend_Paginator? Could you pase some code how you try to use it?

Comment: It's just Zend_Paginator::factory( $allOrders ) where allOrders are the first or second option

Comment: As far as i know, the work you need to do here is already done and delivered with the component Zend/Paginator. you can set the items->meaning rows of the table per page and also you can set the current page and many other features. Taka a look at this.  this may help you . http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$page = $request->getParam('page', 1);

$select = $this->_model->select(); // create select for all records you need
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select));
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage($page * 20);
```

Then pass the $paginator to the view and use just like rowset.

Comment: Yes that's how I do it, but in this case paginator needs this query to finish, I want to tell paginator manually there will be 2000 entries but set query to obtain only first 20 rows

Comment: Zend_Paginator doesn't fetch all rows, it just only count them, which is faster.